# play framework atmosphere

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, atmosphere

There is a list of usable frameworks in [the creators blog](http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/) of `Atmosphere`. I want to use `scala` and the `Play Framework` included with `Atmosphere`. In the blog he writes that Atmosphere works with "every" framework. Could it be that easy to integrate Atmosphere, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, take a look at [this project](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-play) - it's a native implementation of Atmosphere running on top of Play!

Answer (score 3):

I understand that this isn't necessarily the answer you were looking for, but I would suggest you look at Play's native comet support.

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaComet
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/play/api/libs/Comet$.html

Do you have a particular use case that Atmosphere can solve more elegantly? If so, here's a thread that might help.

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/atmosphere-framework/GM6fC6-eSLE

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for this too. The benefits it would give are graceful degradation from websocket to long polling and a common api for these both client and server side.